# Trigger custom Outlook Add-on from External Email notification message

Tags: outlook, microsoft

I have developed an outlook add-on, which gathers email information (Email header etc.) and report it to my custom application.

I want to add a hyperlink in External Email Notification message, when a user click on that hyper link it should trigger already installed outlook add-on (mentioned above).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways but one possibility is:

- Weblink calls PHP page on webserver, which in turn runs a Powershell script via exec command.
- This script adds the AD account to a GPO that enables the add-on DLLs.

There would still be a delay for the GPO to kick in for the user.

Comment: Thanks smwk, but Just want to clarify that add-on is already enabled in outlook. External Email Notification is coming from Exchange server, and I need to add a hyperlink in that notification message and on click of that hyperlink I need to trigger that add-on.

Comment: In theory user clicks on the link, the website sees what IP address the request came from and then a script goes and checks this IP to see if the Outlook addon is enabled. Should be possible with Powershell.